# Why we have limited memory in Embedded System?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, embedded, embedded-linux

I don't know why we have limited memory in Embedded System.

Why we can't use another memory or increase it instead of using high level languages like Rust&go ?

Technology offered many types of memory from lowest memories to 2 TB memories on a sdcard.

Anyway why memory is too important ?

Comment: You can expand memory beyond the natural addressing capability: it is called "bank switching". The question isn't clear though, it seems to be inviting a general discussion about memory configuration and usage.

Comment: Then. why Embedded Engineers trying to decrease those program size ?

Comment: If you plan to build 10,000,000 devices and can use a MCU with 16kB RAM instead of 32kB, thus saving 0.05 USD per device that sounds like a good reason to take care about not wasting memory.

Comment: Being an embedded software engineer I can do an incredible amount with just a few kb. What supprises me is how big frontend software is compared to embedded code ;-) So should your question not be why those other programs use so much.

Comment: Cost.  Die space (for on-chip memory). Complexity - low end MCUs lack SDRAM controllers needed for larger "commodity"  memories. Besides it is not necessarily true that embedded systems are resource constrained - there is a spectrum; while it is true that all Desktop system _need_ Gigabyte of RAM - just to boot and support an OS, many simple single purpose embedded systems do not need that - those that do will run on SBCs such as Raspberry Pi at the low end to full-featured embedded industrial PCs at the other.

Comment: What does "_high level languages like Rust&go_" have to do with the question?  How do those languages help avoid the need to large memories, and what would you use instead given the memory?  Very few embedded systems are implemented using Rust or Go Lang; you may see them referenced a great deal because they are new and people are figuring out how to apply them or earning money writing new books about them.  The bulk of embedded development uses C or C++, and performance rather then memory usage is the primary reason for that.  There is little money in new books about embedded C or C++.

Comment: A single SRAM cell for storing a bit needs like 6 transistors compared to 1 or 2 in DRAM, and it does not need refresh cycles. External memory needs additional pins (especially non-serial interfaces with address and data bus). For our Radar SoCs internal Flash isn't even possible due to the structure/process. Additional 512kB or RAM, especially if you need automotive quality and ECC due to ASIL-B or higher, cost like additional $1. But if you expect like 100 Million ECUs sold, that means 100Million Dollar spent extra for nothing, and you might even be too expensive and can't sell them to OEMs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding memory (and bus to access it, and chip pins for the bus, and a stronger pwoer supply to power it, and more board space, etc.), adds cost; in the most tightly constrained systems every penny counts, so you don't want to spend any more pennies on memory if you can avoid it.

Comment: Umm. Very nice and clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Space, power, processing. There is often very little space to add in an SD card reader (SD card isn't memory! It's storage. Much slower than RAM), embedded systems must optimise for power (embedded systems often don't need the extra RAM, so why spend the power on it?) and often times microcontrollers simply don't have the processing power to handle larger pools of memory. Some processors are still limited to 8 bits! You can't access much memory with an 8 bit or 16 bit pointer.

Answer (score 2):

> *"I don't know why we have limited memory in Embedded System."*

It goes to satisfying the list of specific user needs in the most *efficient* way possible. Its final cost must be competitive and will determine its marketability.

The biggest factor allowing an embedded system to be created with less speed, less memory and use less power than eg an engineering workstation is found in the 1st sentence of this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_system):

> "An embedded system is a computer system—a combination of a computer
> processor, computer memory, and input/output peripheral devices—that
> has ***a dedicated function*** within a larger mechanical or
> electronic system."

It comes down to marketability. Say you are shopping for an internet controlled light switch.  This is an example of a device with *dedicated functionality*, which allows it to be small enough to fit into a space no bigger than a standard wall mounted light switch, use a small limited purpose microprocessor and use only enough memory to run a small application allowing it to respond to a limited number of requests needed to control its output. (eg. timing and switching)  When comparing IoT light controllers you notice several that compete.  Prices are all within a few percentage points of each other.
But if one manufacturer chose to design with memory comparable to what we see on a general purpose desktop computer (the opposite of embedded systems) it would stand out with a huge price difference. It might have the most impressive specifications, but it is not market viable, and it will not compete well against the others.

[More is not always better](http://www.qnx.com/content/dam/qnx/whitepapers/2010/qnx_memory_tech_MC411.77.pdf)...

Answer (score 1):

> low level languages like Rust&go

These are not really low level. Assembler and "bare" C might be. The higher (and more confortable) the language gets, the more complex it gets and needs more memory.

> Anyway why memory is too important

Less memory means more time spent recalculating. Remember that a computer is just a quite simple machine working on a *endless* strip of paper (Turing machine). A lot of algorithms use this space for speed and flexibility.

Comment: Oh that's my fault. *"high level languages".